# Content length transfer chunked

Tags: php, ajax

I have downloaded and upload on free web hosting the guestbook. Demo on download page after posting comment shows the other comments and posted one. I did not change anything and my guestbook after posting comment stays on form. Did not continue to show comments. It is ajax guestbook in php. I run firebug on both and this is what showed.

This is working demo guestbook on developers page picture from firebug:
[Working demo](http://www.upnito.sk/0/fn2n6yhk6aegrve643ndej36fk5nazuf.JPG)

This is what my guestbook page showed from firebug. It does not call the POST gb_view.php and have not content length but have transfer encoding chunked.
[My guestbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqrGP.jpg)

What I can do to make it work as the demo? Please be specific I am noob in PHP and AJAX.
I try to find developers email, I try to find forums, I only find man with same problem, but he never solved it. I do not know how to make it work now.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work when I change in this code

```
function updatepage(str, value){

//if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
if (value == 'signgb'){
document.getElementById("signdiv").innerHTML = str;
showdiv('signdiv');
document.signgb.signbutton.disabled = false;

//Thanks to Hiric for the fix
if (str.length <= 2) { 
  //Create cookie
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(c_minute*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = "signed=yes"+expires+"; path=/";


    hidediv('signform');
    ajax('POST','gb_view.php','page','1');
  }

}else{
document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = str;
showdiv('entries');
}
//}
}
```

This value to bigger:

```
if (str.length <= 2) {
```

I change it to 100 but do not know why it works now and what will be the optimal value...